# How to achieve better consistency with stock / vendor photos taken from different distances?

Tags: website-design, photo-editing, stock-images, photography, white-space

I'm working on an e-commerce site and one problem I face is having to deal with furniture vendors and the way they shoot their photos.

Some shoot products photos up close and others from far back. This prevents the category pages from looking uniform.

As an example (both are 250 x 250):

http://safaviehhome.com/promotional/jpeg.jpg Versus: http://safaviehhome.com/promotional/AMH1522B-SIDE.jpg

Is my only option using a bigger size for the smaller photos?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the community. As it stands this question is very broad. To give you a basic answer: No, of course thats not your only option. There's a lot of options for this, which is why the possibility for an answer is very broad. If you provide us with a bit more context, what you've tried, and what you dislike about your attempt than we can help you solve it.

Comment: Crop the photos or resize them to match.

Comment: The problem with resizing is that some vendors provide lower resolution images (e.g. 750 x 750 whereas we need at least 1500 x 1500) so it's not always an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a simple matter of a two step workflow.

1. Crop all images to allow the same amount of white space around the
   product.
2. Resize the images after the crop so they are all the same size.

That should get all the images the same.

[image]
[image]

<sub>(These are smaller because I only had your 250x250 images to work with)</sub>

Comment: I think this will work best, thanks! But I'm still unsure of how to deal with images that are too small to match the minimum resolution (1500 x 1500). I assume there is nothing I can do in that case?

Comment: Not really, other than A) Enlarge them [which may be okay in some case] or B) request better images.

Comment: @Bitter You could enlarge the smallest and worst picture as much as possible and then use that as a lowest common denominator; give all images the same amount of whitespace as that image.

Comment: @MrE.Upvoter, Scott: Thank you both! I think the lowest common denominator approach will suit me best since requesting better images/enlarging them isn't always an option. P.S. I tried upvoting your answer but don't have enough reputation!

Comment: Not a problem. Just glad you've got a direction which may work :)

Answer (score 2):

### Set some standards based on the limitations of the images you're working with

As discussed in the comments on Scott's answer, a good option is to choose your smallest image, enlarge it as much as possible without visible quality degradation, and then use the same amount of white-space available in that image as the benchmark for all other images.

#### Set a standard for both portrait and landscape images

In the examples you've given us, there is one mildly landscape image, and one heavily portrait image. After a little bit of thought, my best advice is to set-up a canvas upon which all images will be adjusted. Make this canvas as wide and tall as an image is allowed to be, **without** white-space, like so:

[image][image]

Use <kbd>Save for Web...</kbd> on each of the images, resulting in:

[image][image]

Then finally, pop each one into a ready made template with guides, and <kbd>Save for Web...</kbd> again like so:

[image]

Finished Products:

> [image][image]